# How do you fix 'React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency:' warnings?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I get two warnings from these two useEffects. I am learning React.js and this is my first time dealing with this issue.

```
const fetchShippingCountries = async (checkoutTokenId) => {
    const { countries } = await commerce.services.localeListShippingCountries(checkoutTokenId)

useEffect(() => {
    fetchShippingCountries(checkoutToken.id);
  }, []);
```

```
const fetchShippingOptions = async (checkoutTokenId, country, region = null) => {
    const options = await commerce.checkout.getShippingOptions(checkoutTokenId, { country, region });

    setShippingOptions(options);
    setShippingOption(options[0].id);
  }

useEffect(() => {
    if(shippingSubdivision) fetchShippingOptions(checkoutToken.id, shippingCountry, shippingSubdivision);
  }, [shippingSubdivision]);
```

- React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'checkoutToken.id'.
  Either include it or remove the dependency array
- React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'checkoutToken.id' and 'shippingCountry'. Either include them or remove the dependency array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React is asking you to pass the 'checkoutToken.id' and 'shippingCountry' variables into the useEffect dependency array. useEffect is always called whenever the variables within dependency array change. Since you're using these two variables within useEffect, React is warning you that a change in them will not trigger the useEffect.

It's a part of the best practices to add all the variables being used by the useEffect function into the dependency array. This is to make sure you are keeping complete control over the changes within your React app.